# Current month function in MVC Razor

Tags: if-statement, model-view-controller, ddl

```
       Month:@Html.DropDownList("Month", new SelectList(new List<object>
                                        {
                                        new { value = 1 , text = "Jan"},
                                        new { value = 2 , text = "Feb"},
                                        new { value = 3 , text = "Mar"},
                                        new { value = 4 , text = "Apr"},
                                        new { value = 5 , text = "May"},
                                        new { value = 6 , text = "Jun"},
                                        new { value = 7 , text = "Jul"},
                                        new { value = 8 , text = "Aug"},
                                        new { value = 9 , text =  "Sep"},
                                        new { value = 10 , text = "Oct"},
                                        new { value = 11, text = "Nov"},
                                        new { value = 12 , text = "Dec"},
                                        }, "value", "text", 1), new { @onchange = "e_date_changed();", @style = "width:66px" })
                                </div>
                                <div class="DDLabel">
                                    @if()
```

I want the above **DDL month** value into my **if condition** below. how can i do this?

Comment: You should look into using [DateTimeFormatInfo.AbbreviatedMonthNames](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.abbreviatedmonthnames(v=vs.100).aspx), instead of hard coding values (that may include a typo).

Comment: Please give more details about your requirement. But anyway you can use  client side language and find drop-down selected value and then do what ever you want

Comment: Ok how can i get the current month value MVC Razor? with c#

Comment: @SachinYadav In Post Method, pass parameter as  string Month i.e public ActionResult PostAction(string Month){ }

Comment: How can i restore the page values? after using $(document).ready()